# Assertive package and missing data

Tags: r

I apologise if this is missing the obvious, but I cannot find a way to ask assertive to ignore missing data.

Given the following example based on fictional telephone numbers:

```
testfile.data <-    structure(list(goodtelephones = c("01234 567 890", "07987 654 321", 
"08456 234 567"), goodemails = c("bob@email.com", "brian.peter@silly.co.uk", 
"cally_whoosh@email.co.uk"), badtelephones = c("01234 567 890", 
"", "08456 234 567"), bademails = c("bob@email.com", "brian.peter@silly.co.uk", 
"")), .Names = c("goodtelephones", "goodemails", "badtelephones", 
"bademails"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

library(assertive)
```

It was always saying that the columns with missing data are not all postcodes - which I know, because some are missing.  Am I missing an argument or some other way to work around this so that it ignores the missing ones?

```
> is_uk_telephone_number(testfile.data$badtelephones)
01234567890             08456234567 
       TRUE       FALSE        TRUE
```

Comment: The testfile.data$goodpostcodes is not shown here? It simply seems like it is empty.

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to assign the data frame to that name!  (Edited it to correct) And I took the postcodes out this morning which is why it wasn't giving me what it did yesterday - I knew I was being blind!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well spotted, the `assertive` package isn't handling missing values properly in its regex-related functions.

This should return `NA`.

```
is_uk_telephone_number(NA)
##  <NA>
## FALSE
```

I'll get a fix for this a.s.a.p.

---

If you need an instant fix, overwrite the existing function with

```
assignInNamespace(
  "matches_regex",
  function (x, rx, ignore.case = TRUE, ...) 
  {
    call_and_name(
      function(x) 
      {
        ifelse(
          is.na(x), 
          NA, 
          grepl(rx, x, ignore.case = ignore.case, ...)
        )
      }, 
      x
    )
  },
  "assertive"
)
```

Comment: In my defence, the bug seems to be caused by weird behaviour of `grepl` in base R.  `grepl("foo", NA)` returns `FALSE` not `NA`.

Comment: I didn't expect that :)  thank you so much for your swift and helpful response!